# I gave my personal details to a clairvoyant who happens to be a scammer, what are the consequences that awaits?

Tags: scams

Please don't judge me for believing stuff like horoscopes and astrology, though I did not send any amount nor my bank account number. But she knows my birthday, full name and address. What could possibly happen to me? I used an alias on the first month, but I don't know it's like demons really know how to persuade a person who is currently in an unfavorable situation which led me to give my real name and current address. Please enlighten me or tell me if I should worry because my anxiety is killing me.

Comment: If a clairvoyant can't pick me a winning stock or 6 lucky numbers, I really have no use for him/her and I'll just stick to Fortune Cookies.

Comment: Surely the clairvoyant is the best person to ask what the future holds for you? Heck, even if the claim of being clairvoyant is fraudulent, the person on the other end can tell you what the future holds!

Comment: I wouldn't trust a clairvoyant that couldn't tell ME my birthday and name. If they have to ask they are fired!

Comment: @DilipSarwate That may have seemed so very clever when you were writing it, but it's just cruel.  It takes courage to admit that you made a mistake, and snide remarks are not constructive.

Comment: I occasionally find flyers for clairvoyants stuck to the windshield of my car after parking in a public lot.  My only thought is "if they were really clairvoyant, they'd have known better."

Comment: On a more serious note: What makes you think the clairvoyant is really a scammer?  There are lots of clairvoyants out there who do what they do for "entertainment purposes" (of the customer, one assumes.)  What reason do you have to think this one might have malicious intentions?  Did they *ask* for banking details, etc?

Answer (score 6):

I will vote to close this question as a duplicate of this one:

[I gave a scammer my telephone number, address, and name. How bad is it?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/66872/i-gave-a-scammer-my-telephone-number-address-and-name-how-bad-is-it)

However, that anxiety you are feeling probably has a much deeper cause and enabled you to fall for something you should not have. You know better. I would encourage you to seek some help with that anxiety and explore the reasons you are looking for solutions to life's problems in the spiritual realm.

As adults we solve problems, typically, by changing behavior or throwing money at them.  Often we have to do both. In order to have that money, we have to earn it.  That means getting out and working not seeking the advice of some medium. It has opened you up to scammers only causing more problems.

As the linked question says you are probably not in much trouble unless you continue to give information. So stop and find the reason you stared in the first place.